# Is there a google sketchup mode?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

That blender would basically emulate a basic google sketchup interface, with grid snapping, mouse bindings, selectable surfaces, and all that jazz?

Answer (score 6):

There is no one click button to make blender act just like sketchup, but most of what you want can be done.

To turn on grid snapping press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

By "Selectable surfaces" I think you would want to select a face. So in edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle in and out of edit mode) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> > *Face*.

All keyboard shortcuts and mouse actions can be changed through the user preferences. *File > User Preferences* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> then the *Input* tab.