# What free tools make Blender work like SketchUp?

Tags: modeling, interface, add-on, tools

I'm coming from SketchUp and want to find tools, that are free, to make Blender work like SketchUp. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Has anyone made any that convert Blender into a user-friendly CAD program? How do I also have all the privative shape icons always open?

Comment: Hi! This is not reddit rather a Q&A site, please read about how to ask a good question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please be specific. What tools are you in need of?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-google-sketchup-mode

Comment: Blender is not Sketchup and never will be. You'll be much happier in the long run if you face that fact now and learn to use its tools for what they are.